# Why am I running out of heap memory?

Tags: c++, memory, overflow, raytracing, msaa

So I'm writing a raytracer in C++ using Jetbrains Clion IDE. When I try to create a 600 * 600 image with multisampling antialiasing enabled, I run out of memory. I get this error:

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
>   what():  std::bad_alloc
>
> This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an
>   unusual way. Please contact the application's support team for more
>   information.

Code of my render function:

width: 600
height: 600
numberOfSamples: 80

```
void Camera::render(const int width, const int height){
    int resolution = width * height;
    double scale = tan(Algebra::deg2rad(fov * 0.5));  //deg to rad
    ColorRGB *pixels = new ColorRGB[resolution];
    long loopCounter = 0;
    Vector3D camRayOrigin = getCameraPosition();
    for (int i = 0; i < width; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < height; ++j) {
            double zCamDir = (height/2) / scale;
            ColorRGB finalColor = ColorRGB(0,0,0,0);
            int tempCount = 0;
            for (int k = 0 ; k < numberOfSamples; k++) {
                tempCount++;
                //If it is single sampled, then we want to cast ray in the middle of the pixel, otherwise we offset the ray by a random value between 0-1
                double randomNumber = Algebra::getRandomBetweenZeroAndOne();
                double xCamDir = (i - (width / 2)) + (numberOfSamples == 1 ? 0.5 : randomNumber);
                double yCamDir = ((height / 2) - j) + (numberOfSamples == 1 ? 0.5 : randomNumber);
                Vector3D camRayDirection = convertCameraToWorldCoordinates(Vector3D(xCamDir, yCamDir, zCamDir)).unitVector();
                Ray r(camRayOrigin, camRayDirection);
                finalColor = finalColor + getColorFromRay(r);
            }
            pixels[loopCounter] = finalColor / numberOfSamples;
            loopCounter++;
        }
    }
    CreateImage::createRasterImage(height, width, "RenderedImage.bmp", pixels);
    delete pixels;      //Release memory
}
```

I'm a beginner in C++, so I'd really appreciate your help. I also tried doing the same thing in C# in Microsoft Visual Studio and the memory usage never exceeded 200MB. I feel like I'm doing some mistake. I can provide you with more details if you want to help me.

Comment: Are you using expensive functions? That may be the reason besides not deallocating the memory.

Answer (score 2):

Memory allocated using `new []` must be deallocated using `delete []`.

Your program has undefined behavior due to use of

```
delete pixels;      //Release memory
```

to deallocate memory.  It needs to be:

```
delete [] pixels;
```

Comment: I'm sorry it had no effect whatsoever.

Comment: @sashankAryal, I can't see anything else that stands out as a problem. It will be helpful if you can come up with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).